# How to convert alfresco ant based project in alfresco5 maven based?

Tags: maven, ant, alfresco, alfresco-share

I  am using alfresco 4.1.3 having following project structure.

[image]

I am using the ant script to build project.
Now I want to convert this project into maven based alfresco5. 
I have configured alfresco5 using all-in-one archetype and I am able to run it successfully. My questions are:

**How can I convert my alfresco ant based project in alfresco5 maven based?**

**Do I need to add src files in repo or repo-amp?**

**Do I need to copy all share related files in share or share-amp?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks in Advance.!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That totally depends on the ant build setup. But one good guess is that you will have to put the files residing in the "Alfresco" folder of your old project into different subfolders of the repo-amp, and the same way around with the "Share" folder. Most files will go into those folders, you have to study the SDK-docs carefully to know into which folders the files will go. Depending of the nature of your extensions some files could go into the Share and Alfresco war-structure as well (additions to web.xml for example).

There are no "Swiss army knife" for that works for all cases here.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Do the following things:

1. Create new project as maven project and provide group id (it's yours) artifact id as alfresco5 and version (ex:43.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
2. With this it creates maven based folder structure
   src/main/java -> replace it with your src folder
   3.src/main/resources ->add your Share, reference and Alfresco folders.
3. look at you lib directory..what ever .jar will be there you need to define it in dependencies under pom.xml
4. compile the whole project..if there are compilation errors then add required dependencies in pom.xml